# Does the $M/L$ ratio have an implied band?

Tags: cosmology, galaxies, luminosity

When I look at the NED database, I see the Luminosity quoted for six different bands (X-Ray, UV, Visible, Near IR, Far IR, Radio).  My issue is trying to interpret the $M/L$ ratios I've seen referenced in several articles to the values in the NED database. Sometimes the band is included (e.g. $M/Lv$), but more often it isn't. When I see someone quote an $M/L$ ratio without qualification, is there an assumed band?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a specified band, since the $M/L$ values for a given stellar population vary with the band. It's possible that since traditionally galaxy luminosities were measured in $B$ more than any other band, there may be some cases where that's what is meant. (It's also possible that someone quoting an $M/L$ ratio has earlier specified what the band of their imaging/photometry is.)